# C++ vector adding elements efficiently

Tags: c++, memory-management, stdvector

Suppose I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class X {
public:
  int x[1000];
  X(int y) { for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) x[i] = y; }
};

int main() {
  vector<X> v;
  X x0(0);
  X x1(1);
  X x2(2);
  v.push_back(x0);
  v.push_back(x1);
  v.push_back(x2);
  cout << v[2].x[33] << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

If I understand correctly, in my code, I am allocating memory on the stack for `x0`, `x1` and `x2`, then copying those contents onto memory allocated for me by `vector`. Furthermore, as far as I understand, move semantics can't help here because it's not exactly like `X` is holding a pointer to resource located somewhere else.

Is it possible for me to directly call the constructor on the raw memory block allocated for me by `vector`? If not, what would be the proper way to handle situations like these?

Comment: my unsolicited advice: Don't make classes that large.

Comment: 4K of data in a struct is too much for you? A couple of regular char arrays will get you there without even realizing it.

Comment: Move semantics are mainly useful for *handle-like* classes. Which leads to the question: Why are you fighting the language?. If the `x[1000]` is a placeholder for structures you can not reveal here, my next question is are those structures *handle-like*? If you are really using that large arrays use vector<int>. Don't fight the language.

Comment: @StilesCrisis: Yes, generally, it's too much for me.  Precisely for the obvious reason that it makes moving the class objects way too expensive.  Why would I have a couple of char arrays of size 2000 in a struct, other than for very specific purposes, and not generally for the kinds of objects that I have enough of that I would want to put them in a vector?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use C++11's `emplace_back`.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back

Also, if you're concerned about excess copies/moves, try starting with `v.reserve(3)`.

Comment: It's also surprisingly easy to do this in C++03 with iterators IIRC

Comment: A no-copy vector `push_back` in C++03 with iterators? Do tell.

Comment: @StilesCrisis: Pass a temporary and let the optimizing compiler do what it does.

Comment: How does that involve iterators?

Comment: @StilesCrisis: I didn't say with `push_back`, I just said creating the elements in place with iterators.  `v.assign(begin, end);` or similar.

Comment: You can create them in-place if you can live with default construction. I think this example is specifically about construction with argument passing.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `std::ref` or `boost::ref` if available and store a reference of the object in the vector, thus avoiding the copy.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

class X {
public:
  int x[1000];
  X(int y) { for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) x[i] = y; }
};

int main() {
  std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<X> > v;
  X x0(0);
  X x1(1);
  X x2(2);


  v.push_back(std::ref(x0));
  v.push_back(std::ref(x1));
  v.push_back(std::ref(x2));
  cout << v[2].get().x[33] << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cool trick, but doesn't work if `x0` and friends ever go out of scope while the vector still lives... this makes it hard to use for general purpose stuff.